# Sending parameters from textbox to stored procedure if values have changed C#

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

I am hoping someone can bring some clarity to the problem that I am facing. I have a few textboxes, datepickers and a save button.

What I would like to be able to do is, check if the values any of the values have changed and run a stored procedure with the parameters from my textboxes/datepickers. There's instances where only the Average Rate changes and the date associated but the Overtime remains the same. There's no reason to duplicate the Overtime row. It's also not clear to me how to pass the existing value in the textbox as the existing value (p_OldAmount) and the newly typed one (p_NewAmount). Please help me better understand how to solve this.

What would be my best approach here and how can I tie everything together? Sorry for the poor attempt at this but here's how far I've got:

```
Id Location DateFrom   DateTo     RateType      Rate  Description
1  LA       01/01/2017 01/01/2018 Average Rate  20    none
2  LA       01/01/2017 01/01/2018 Overtime Rate 30
```

**Working:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : 
{
public MainWindow()
{
InitializeComponent();
string connectionString = "datasource=;port=;username=;password=";

MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

MySqlCommand lAR= new MySqlCommand("Select RateType from Daily.Rates where RateType = 'Average Hourly Wages'", connection);
MySqlCommand sAR = new MySqlCommand("Select Amount from Daily.Rates where RateType = 'Average Rate'", connection);
MySqlCommand sARF = new MySqlCommand("Select DateFrom from Daily.Rates where RateType = 'Average Rate'", connection);
MySqlCommand sART = new MySqlCommand("Select DateTo from Daily.Rates where RateType = 'Average Rate'", connection);
MySqlCommand sARC = new MySqlCommand("Select Description from Daily.Rates where RateType = 'Average Rate'", connection);

MySqlCommand lAR= new MySqlCommand("Select RateType from Daily.Rates where RateType = 'Overtime Rate'", connection);
MySqlCommand sOTR = new MySqlCommand("Select Amount from Daily.Rates where RateType = 'Overtime Rate'", connection);
MySqlCommand sOTRF = new MySqlCommand("Select DateFrom from Daily.Rates where RateType = 'Overtime Rate'", connection);
MySqlCommand sOTRT = new MySqlCommand("Select DateTo from Daily.Rates where RateType = 'Overtime Rate'", connection);
MySqlCommand sOTRC = new MySqlCommand("Select Description from Daily.Rates where RateType = 'Overtime Rate'", connection);

try
{
    connection.Open();
    {
    lblAHW.Content = lAHW.ExecuteScalar();
    txtAverageRate.Text = sAR.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    dfAverageRate.Text = sARF.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    dtAverageRate.Text = sART.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    txtcommAverageRate.Text = sARC.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

    txtOTRW.Text = sOTR.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    dfOTR.Text = sOTRF.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    dtOTR.Text = sOTRT.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    txtcommOTR.Text = sOTRC.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
connection.Close();
}
```

**Giving me trouble:**

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
string connectionString = "datasource=;port=;username=;password=";
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

try
    {
    connection.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UpdateRate", connection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_DateFrom", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = dfAverageRate.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_NewAmount", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = txtAverageRate.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_OldAmount", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = this.txtAverageRate.Text;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_DateFrom", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = dfOTRate.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_NewAmount", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = txtOTRate.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_OldAmount", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = this.txtOTRate.Text;
    }
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

**Stored Procedure:**

```
CREATE DEFINER=``@`%` PROCEDURE `UpdateRate`(
    IN `p_DateFrom` DATETIME,
    IN `p_NewAmount` DECIMAL(10,2),
    IN `p_OldAmount` DECIMAL(10,2),
    IN `p_RateType` VARCHAR(50)
)
BEGIN

INSERT INTO Daily.Rates
(Location, DateFrom, DateTo, RateType, Amount, Description)
SELECT Location, p_DateFrom, DateTo, RateType, p_NewAmount, Description
FROM Daily.Rates
WHERE Amount=p_OldAmount AND RateType=p_RateType;

UPDATE Daily.Rates
SET DateTo=DATE_SUB(p_DateFrom, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
WHERE Amount=p_OldAmount AND RateType=p_RateType;

END
```

Result after running stored procedure with `p_DateFrom=2017-10-13, p_OldAmount=20, p_NewAmount=22:`

```
Id Location DateFrom   DateTo     RateType      Rate  Description
1  LA       01/01/2017 10/12/2018 Average Rate  20    none
2  LA       01/01/2017 01/01/2018 Overtime Rate 30 
3  LA       10/13/2017 01/01/2018 Average Rate  22    none
```

**Current attempt:**

```
internal static string oldAmount = string.Empty;
internal static string oldAmount2 = string.Empty;

private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
string connectionString = "datasource=;port=;username=;password=";
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

try
    {
    connection.Open();

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UpdateRate", connection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_DateFrom", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = dfAverageRate.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_NewAmount", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = txtAverageRate.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_OldAmount", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = oldAmount;
    // ***this works: cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_OldAmount", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = 20;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_DateFrom", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = dfOTRate.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_NewAmount", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = txtOTRate.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_OldAmount", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = oldAmount2;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    oldAmount = this.txtAverageRate.Text; 
    oldAmount2 = this.txtOTRate.Text; 
    connection.Close();

    }
catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

**2nd attempt:**

```
private string UpdateRate(DateTime dateFrom, string newRate, string oldRate, string ratetype)
{
    string connectionString = "datasource=;port=;Initial Catalog=;username=;password=";
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

    try
    {
        connection.Open();

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UpdateRate", connection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_DateFrom", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = dateFrom;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_NewAmount", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = newRate;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_OldAmount", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = oldRate;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_RateType", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ratetype;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show(oldAverageRate, "Test", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
        connection.Close();
        return newRate;

    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    return null;

}

internal static string oldAverageRate;
internal static string oldOvertimeRate;

private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    oldAverageRate = this.txtAverageRate.Text;
    oldAverageRate = UpdateRate(dfAHW.SelectedDate.Value, txtAverageRate.Text, oldAverageRate, lblAverageRate.ToString());
    oldOvertimeRate = this.txtOvertimeRate.Text;
    oldOvertimeRate = UpdateRate(dfOTHW.SelectedDate.Value, txtOTRate.Text, oldOvertimeRate, lblOvertimeRate.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Can't you store the existing value (`p_OldAmount`) in a variable?

Comment: Sounds good. Can you please show me how would you do it?

Comment: How does this compile? Shouldn't the `try` block be followed immediately by the `catch` block?

Comment: Thank for pointing that out. I've edited my answer. It almost works so if you have a better suggestion please provide an example. Thank you Adam!

Comment: It looks like you're adding the same parameters to the `cmd` twice. Are you calling `ExecuteNonQuery` in the middle? (Not certain that'd work; you may need to turn this into two separate `cmd` objects.)

Comment: I've been testing it with only the first set of parameters but it doesn't work, my oldValue variable does not hold the original value in the textbox before any change. It's good to know that I have to call ExecuteNonQuery multiple times based on the set of parameters. Can you please help me with a better approach Adam?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better approach is to move the update call to a separate method altogether:

```
private string UpdateRate(DateTime dateFrom, string newRate, string oldRate)
{
    string connectionString = "datasource=;port=;username=;password=";
    var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    try
    {
        connection.Open();

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UpdateRate", connection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_DateFrom", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = dateFrom;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_NewAmount", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = newRate;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_OldAmount", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = oldRate;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return newRate;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then you can call it from the `btnSave_Click` method:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    oldAverageRate = UpdateRate(dfAverageRate.SelectedDate.Value, txtAverageRate.Text, oldAverageRate);
    oldOvertimeRate = UpdateRate(dfOTRate.SelectedDate.Value, txtOTRate.Text, oldOvertimeRate);
}
```

I would also ensure that your static fields are appropriately set at the very beginning:

```
// Add these in your MainWindow logic that retrieves the initial data
oldAverageRate = txtAverageRate.Text = sAR.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

oldOvertimeRate = txtOTRW.Text = sOTR.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Other things I'd consider changing:

- I would want to put the `new MySqlConnection(...)` and `new MySqlCommand(...)` commands into `using` statements, but I can't find anything that says whether or not they implement `IDisposable`.
- Alternately, you could open the connection once, pass the connection object to the method, and then close it when everything was complete.
- You should definitely take the `connectionString` out of your code and put it into a config file, so that changing the database server doesn't require a code change and recompile.
- Once you get this working, then you can consider converting the strings to `decimal` objects, but you'll need to add error checking to ensure the code doesn't attempt to write invalid values to the database. (As a matter of fact, I'd do the error checking either way.)

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear explanation and your advice Adam. I really like the approach and I tried it your way and I cannot get it to work. It still passes the newly changed value as the oldAmount. I am not implementing IDisposable but I will try to learn how to do it. I will follow your advice regarding the config file once I get it working. Can you please help me to get this off the ground? It's really been killing me for the past few days and I just can't get around it, maybe I'm just too much of a beginner. Can you some me how to convert to decimal and where to close the connection?

Comment: When you say "it still passes the newly changed value as the oldAmount", what do you mean, exactly?

Comment: To be more exact: when the window loads the value is set to 20. If I change that to 55, the oldAmount parameter is set to 55 instead of 20. So I need "@p_NewAmount" = 55 and "@p_oldAmount"=20. The stored procedure retrieves  "@p_oldAmount"=55. Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: When are you initially setting `oldAmount`? I don't see that variable being updated until after the first time you call `UpdateRate`. (BTW, to avoid confusion, I've renamed the variables in my example to make them more clear than `oldAmount` and `oldAmount2`. I hope the new names still make sense.)

Comment: I have updated my answer with a 2nd attempt at this. I could not get it to work this way, I have also noticed that my stored procedure is called differently now: instead of copying the first row and updating the dateto, it does the update first and then duplicates the row, which is strange. Can you please have a look at what I have now. I have added a bounty on this, I really want to get this to work and I need your help. Thank you.

Comment: Note that before, you only called the stored procedure once (one `ExecuteNonQuery` call); that could be why you're getting different DB results now. If you want to be certain you're updating the appropriate data, I'd add the `RateType` as a parameter to your stored procedure and pass it in each time you call it.

Comment: That's a brilliant idea. I'll try that right now. If you have any other suggestions that could help please show me by editing your answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: I have edited my stored procedure(see updated question) and indeed it's a huge improvement. Can you please help me put it all together? I am still struggling and I cannot get a result. I have no idea how to pass the RateType now. I am not displaying it in a textbox. How can I get it work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156865/discussion-between-icosmin-and-adam-v).

Comment: Adding those lines to my MainWindow logic really helped. There's only one thing that doesn't get updated anymore: the Update part from my stored procedure. It inserts a new row with the correct value but it doesn't update the old row. So instead of having DateTo = Today - 1 (10/15/2017) on the old rate, it stays 01/012018.

Answer (score 2):

Save your old value in a variable on `Save`.

```
internal static string oldAmount = string.Empty;
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ... 
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_OldAmount", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = oldAmount;

    oldAmount = this.txtOTRate.Text;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and help. I've tried it this way and it makes a lot of sense. However nothing happens when I click the button. The stored procedure does not run. There's still something missing but I just can't see it. Can you please advise?

Comment: @iCosmin I haven't done ADO.NET in a long time, but seems like you only "Open" the connection and add params to the command. I don't see you `executing` the command.

Comment: You are right! Thank you for pointing that out. I have edited my question. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: "Input string was not in the correct format". I can seem to figure out what's throwing this error. Do you have any idea how can I fix it?

Comment: @iCosmin, I don't know where the error is throwing... Best to make another SO question with the relevant supporting code for that.

Comment: I've figured out the rest but no matter how I try it, you solution doesn't solve my problem. I cannot accept it as an answer. If you have other ideas, please advise. The problem is here: oldAmount = this.txtOTRate.Text;. It doesn't get through, but with a hardcoded value it works.

Comment: I am quite positive that, that line is not throwing the error, seems like you are converting your text box value to which is not a valid format you are expecting.. `oldAmount` is type of `string` so is `txtOTRate.Text` no errors should be thrown there. So you are doing something else with it that I am not aware of.

Comment: I am not getting an error anymore so there's no problem with the format. The problem is with the oldAmount variable. It doesn't get stored and passed to the stored procedure. It doesn't retain the old value. E.g.: 20 is my old value. If I change that to 22, my oldAmount variable is 22 instead of 20. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Edit your question with EDIT at the end and provide your current code for it

Comment: Thank you very much! I have edited my question. Please advise.

Comment: @iCosmin your edited code is different then my answer, those `oldAmount` should be set at the end of your code. What's happening is that you are setting a new value every time that method is executed, before the stored procedure is executed

Comment: I have tried it both ways and it didn't work. Can you please edit you answer based on my new edit. Do I need to set the oldAmount after cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); ? Thank you.

Comment: Yes after execute

Comment: I have tried it after execute and it doesn't work. I get the following error: "Input string was not in a correct format." I know it's a problem with the oldAmount variable because it works with a hard coded value. Please see my updated question.

Comment: I think the oldValues should be stored as decimal, because I am using  MySqlDbType.Decimal. I have tried it like this: internal static decimal oldAmount = decimal.Zero;  oldAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(this.txtAHW.Text); but it returns zero. How can we get around this?

Answer (score 1):

- Don't select each column separately; `SELECT a, b, c FROM ...`
- Don't mix `DECIMAL` and `FLOAT` values.  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.
- Don't use Cursors if you can get away without them; SQL is excellent at doing things en masse.
- Do put quotes around dates, else `2017-10-13,` is subtraction and becomes 1994.
- Do connect only once.  That is the connect code is usually outside functions.  *Edit:*  I'm not a C# programmer, but I would guess that the Connect could be done in the 'constructor' and the `connection` can be stored in a attribute for use by the various methods.
- Do test the SQL using the commandline "mysql" before putting in code, where it becomes messier to distinguish SQL problems from code problems.
- Do use DATE_ADD to compute DateTo from DateFrom??  *Edit:*  Or does "from" come after "to"?  (Or did I get it backwards?)
- Explain this strange patter:  `INSERT INTO rates ... SELECT ... FROM rates ...`.  And then explain the `UPDATE rates` right after it.

Comment: Thank you for offering to help Rick. Please see bellow my answer to your every point. Hopefully we can get this to work and I could learn something valuable from you. Please advise.

Comment: @iCosmin - I commented on 2 items; see _Edits_.  I did not expect to fix all your issues; just the ones that jumped out at me.

Comment: I took a look at the edits Rick. Thanks for your help. DateFrom comes before DateTo. Do you have any suggestions on the stored procedure? What can I improve?